# What are the Next and Previous pointers of a circular doubly linkedlist if theres only one node?

Tags: linked-list, doubly-linked-list

suppose if in a **circular doubly LinkedList**, there is only One node present, *what will be the* **Next** and **Previous** pointers *of that node?* Will they be **null** or they'll be pointing to that only existing node?

Answer (score 0):

A **double linked list** can hold head and tail pointers.
Then first's node prev an last's node next can be null.

A **double linked circular list** lets the first's prev and last's next point to last (tail) and resp. first (head). It then can do **without tail**, as that would be head.prev.